# How do I use SSO in my Spring Security Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests
//                        .requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/", "/node_modules/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2Login()

    }
}
```

With this code I can log in via oauth2 and a third party IDP. How can I get the application to check the IDP for a session on every request and then use it (SSO)?

I tried following:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests
//                        .requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/", "/node_modules/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2Login()
                .userInfoEndpoint()
                .userService(oauth2UserService());
    }

    private OAuth2UserService<OAuth2UserRequest, OAuth2User> oauth2UserService() {
        DefaultOAuth2UserService delegate = new DefaultOAuth2UserService();
        return userRequest -> {
            OAuth2User oAuth2User = delegate.loadUser(userRequest);
            // You can customize the OAuth2User object here, if needed
            return oAuth2User;
        };
    }
}
```

I expected a redirect to the IDP to happen when the page is opened and then logs me in automatically. However, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean nothing happens? If the resource is protected and you aren't authenticated the redirect should happen to the login form of the IdP. If the resource is protected and you are authenticated then the IdP should redirect you back to your application seamlessly - this is to be expected for SSO, you should be able to see the flow in the network tab of your browser. If the resource isn't protected at all then your application should reject you by default (depending on your version of spring) or allow you to access it without consulting the IdP.